# React Native WebRTC Remote Stream is black

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, socket.io-client, react-native-webrtc

React Native Webrtc remote stream is black during Video Call. It's getting both audio/video from remote candidate but it just won't display.

```
{"_id": "28967b2b-d555-4438-a8e8-b415e1831998", "_reactTag": "1658015a-9780-45ad-aa1a-b7d4829a1ee0", "_tracks": [{"_constraints": [Object], "_enabled": true, "_muted": false, "_peerConnectionId": 62, "_readyState": "live", "_settings": [Object], "id": "b32d8b02-4297-4650-b104-1b95abdfaef2", "kind": "audio", "label": "", "remote": true}, {"_constraints": [Object], "_enabled": true, "_muted": true, "_peerConnectionId": 62, "_readyState": "live", "_settings": [Object], "id": "c23b7813-7918-44fe-b9c3-237adb033900", "kind": "video", "label": "", "remote": true}]}
```

Here's the code for my Video Call Screen

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  Image,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ToastAndroid,
} from "react-native";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {
  mediaDevices,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
} from "react-native-webrtc";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { useNetInfo } from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import InCallManager from "react-native-incall-manager";

import IncomingCallModal from "../../../components/modals/IncomingCallModal";
import LetterImage from "../../../components/LetterImage";
import OngoingCallModal from "../../../components/modals/OngoingCallModal";
import Text from "../../../components/Text";

import useAuth from "../../../auth/useAuth";
import useSocket from "../../../utils/socket";
import useUtils from "../../../utils";

import callsApi from "../../../api/calls";

import { videoImg } from "../../../assets/images";
import colors from "../../../config/colors";

import logger from "../../../utils/logger";
import routes from "../../../navigation/routes";

import { getDeviceIp } from "../../../utils/ip";

function VideoCallScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { contact, callState, callId, navigatedFrom } = route.params;
  const { isConnected, isInternetReachable } = useNetInfo();

  const { user } = useAuth();
  const { closeAndReinstantiatePeerConnection, peerConnection, stopStreams } =
    useUtils();
  const {
    answerCall,
    cancelTimeout,
    checkWebRTCServerStatus,
    outgoingCall,
    socket,
    sendCall,
    sendICEcandidate,
  } = useSocket();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigatedFrom && callId) {
      socket.emit("navigated", { calleeId: otherUserId.current });
    }
  }, [callId, navigatedFrom]);

  const otherUserId = useRef(contact?.mobile);
  const remoteRTCMessage = useRef();
  const [isCalling, setIsCalling] = useState(false);
  const [type, setType] = useState(callState ? callState : "VIDEO_CALL");
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(null);
  const [localMicOn, setlocalMicOn] = useState(true);
  const [localWebcamOn, setlocalWebcamOn] = useState(true);
  const [mainCallId, setMainCallId] = useState("");
  const timeoutID = useRef();

  console.log(remoteStream);

  const initStream = async () => {
    let isFront = false;

    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((sourceInfos) => {
      let videoSourceId;

      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];

        if (
          sourceInfo.kind == "videoinput" &&
          sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? "user" : "environment")
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }

      mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: true,
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          setLocalStream(stream);

          stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
            peerConnection.current.addTrack(track, stream);
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          logger.log("Could not get media stream");
          logger.log(error);
        });
    });
  };

  async function processCall() {
    if (isInternetReachable === false && isConnected === false) {
      return alert("Check your phone's  internet connection and try again.");
    }

    const status = await checkWebRTCServerStatus();
    if (status === false) {
      return alert("Call could not connect!");
    }

    InCallManager.start({ media: "audio", ringback: "_DTMF_" });
    // await initStream();

    const {
      coords: { latitude, longitude },
    } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.LocationAccuracy.BestForNavigation,
    });
    setIsCalling(true);

    const res = await callsApi.addCall(
      {
        status: "outgoing",
        callType: "video",
        receiver: contact.name,
        mobile: contact.mobile,
      },
      { latitude, longitude }
    );

    if (res.ok) {
      setMainCallId(res.data.call._id);

      const data = {
        calleeId: contact.mobile,
        callInfo: {
          callType: "video",
          caller: {
            name: user.name,
            mobile: user.mobile,
          },
          callState: "INCOMING_CALL",
          callId: res.data.call._id,
        },
      };

      outgoingCall(data);

      timeoutID.current = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsCalling(false);
        InCallManager.stopRingback();
        InCallManager.stop();

        socket.emit("callTimeout", { calleeId: otherUserId.current });

        ToastAndroid.show("Call ended", ToastAndroid.SHORT);

        navigation.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [
            { name: "TabNavigator" },
            { name: "AudioCall" },
            { name: "VideoCall" },
          ],
        });
      }, 32000);
    }
  }

  const send = async () => {
    // 1. Caller runs the `createOffer` method for getting SDP.
    const sessionDescription = await peerConnection.current.createOffer();

    // 2. Caller sets the local description using `setLocalDescription`.
    await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);

    sendCall({
      calleeId: otherUserId.current,
      rtcMessage: sessionDescription,
    });
  };

  const updateCall = async (id, status) => {
    const {
      coords: { latitude, longitude },
    } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();

    if (callId) {
      await callsApi.updateCall(
        {
          callStatus: status,
          callId: id,
          mateId: user.id,
        },
        { longitude, latitude }
      );
    }
  };

  async function processAccept() {
    cancelTimeout(otherUserId.current);
    // await initStream();

    const {
      coords: { latitude, longitude },
    } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.LocationAccuracy.BestForNavigation,
    });

    await callsApi.updateCall(
      {
        callStatus: "ongoing",
        callId,
        receiverId: user.id,
      },
      { longitude, latitude }
    );

    // 4. Bob sets the description, Alice sent him as the remote description using `setRemoteDescription()
    // try {
    await peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(
      new RTCSessionDescription(remoteRTCMessage.current)
    );

    // 5. Bob runs the `createAnswer` method
    const sessionDescription = await peerConnection.current.createAnswer();

    // 6. Bob sets that as the local description and sends it to Alice
    await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);

    answerCall({
      callerId: otherUserId.current,
      rtcMessage: sessionDescription,
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initStream();

    socket.on("callTimeout", () => {
      setIsCalling(false);
      leave();

      updateCall(callId, "missed");
      setType("VIDEO_CALL");

      ToastAndroid.show("Call ended", ToastAndroid.SHORT);

      navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [
          { name: "TabNavigator" },
          { name: "AudioCall" },
          { name: "VideoCall" },
        ],
      });
    });

    socket.on("cancelTimeout", () => {
      if (timeoutID.current) {
        console.log("Clearing timeoutID", timeoutID.current);
        clearTimeout(timeoutID.current);

        InCallManager.stopRingback();
      }
    });

    socket.on("callEnded", () => {
      streamCleanup();
      stopStreams();
      closeAndReinstantiatePeerConnection();

      setIsCalling(false);
      setType("VIDEO_CALL");

      ToastAndroid.show("Call ended", ToastAndroid.SHORT);

      InCallManager.stop();
      InCallManager.stopRingback();

      navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [
          { name: "TabNavigator" },
          { name: "AudioCall" },
          { name: "VideoCall" },
        ],
      });
    });

    socket.on("newCall", (data) => {
      remoteRTCMessage.current = data.rtcMessage;
      otherUserId.current = data.callerId;

      setType("INCOMING_CALL");
    });

    socket.on("navigated", () => {
      send();
    });

    socket.on("callAnswered", (data) => {
      remoteRTCMessage.current = data.rtcMessage;

      peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(
        new RTCSessionDescription(remoteRTCMessage.current)
      );

      if (timeoutID.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID.current);
      }

      setType("WEBRTC_ROOM");
      InCallManager.stopRingback();

      logger.log("Remote Stream", remoteStream);
    });

    socket.on("ICEcandidate", (data) => {
      let message = data.rtcMessage;

      if (peerConnection.current) {
        peerConnection?.current
          .addIceCandidate(
            new RTCIceCandidate({
              candidate: message.candidate,
              sdpMid: message.id,
              sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
            })
          )
          .then((data) => {
            logger.log("SUCCESS");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            logger.log("Error", err);
          });
      }
    });

    socket.on("endCall", () => {
      // Receive the signal to end the call from the caller
      setIsCalling(false);
      setType("VIDEO_CALL");
    });

    peerConnection.current.onaddstream = (event) => {
      if (event.stream) {
        logger.log("Setting Remote Stream", event.stream);
        setRemoteStream(event.stream);
      }
    };

    peerConnection.current.ontrack = (event) => {
      if (event.streams && event.streams.length > 0) {
        logger.log("Setting Remote Stream: ontrack", event.streams[0]);
        setRemoteStream(event.streams[0]);
      }
    };

    // Setup ice handling
    peerConnection.current.onicecandidate = (event) => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        logger.log("Sending ICE", event.candidate);
        sendICEcandidate({
          calleeId: otherUserId.current,
          rtcMessage: {
            label: event.candidate.toJSON().sdpMLineIndex,
            id: event.candidate.toJSON().sdpMid,
            candidate: event.candidate.toJSON().candidate,
          },
        });
      } else {
        logger.log("End of candidates.");
      }
    };

    const cleanup = () => {
      if (peerConnection.current) {
        closeAndReinstantiatePeerConnection();
      }

      if (localStream) {
        localStream.release();
      }

      if (remoteStream) {
        remoteStream.release();
      }
    };

    return () => {
      socket.off("newCall");
      socket.off("callAnswered");
      socket.off("ICEcandidate");
      socket.off("callEnded");
      socket.off("callTimeout");
      socket.off("navigated");

      cleanup();
    };
  }, []);

  async function leave() {
    closeAndReinstantiatePeerConnection();
    streamCleanup();
    stopStreams();

    socket.emit("endCall", { calleeId: otherUserId.current });

    setIsCalling(false);
    setType("VIDEO_CALL");
  }

  const streamCleanup = () => {
    if (localStream) {
      localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        track.enabled = false;
        track.stop();
      });

      localStream.release();
    }

    if (remoteStream) {
      remoteStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        track.stop();
      });

      remoteStream.release();
    }

    setLocalStream(null);
    setRemoteStream(null);
  };

  function switchCamera() {
    localStream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => {
      track._switchCamera();
    });
  }

  function toggleCamera() {
    localWebcamOn ? setlocalWebcamOn(false) : setlocalWebcamOn(true);

    localStream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => {
      localWebcamOn ? (track.enabled = false) : (track.enabled = true);
    });
  }

  function toggleMic() {
    localMicOn ? setlocalMicOn(false) : setlocalMicOn(true);
    localStream.getAudioTracks().forEach((track) => {
      localMicOn ? (track.enabled = false) : (track.enabled = true);
    });
  }

  switch (type) {
    case "INCOMING_CALL":
      return (
        <IncomingCallModal
          otherUserId={otherUserId.current}
          caller={contact}
          hangup={() => {
            leave();

            updateCall(callId, "missed");

            setIsCalling(false);

            navigation.reset({
              index: 0,
              routes: [
                { name: "TabNavigator" },
                { name: "AudioCall" },
                { name: "VideoCall" },
              ],
            });
          }}
          join={() => {
            processAccept();

            setTimeout(() => {
              setType("WEBRTC_ROOM");
            }, 3000);
          }}
        />
      );
    case "WEBRTC_ROOM":
      return (
        <View style={styles.webRTCContainer}>
          {/* {localWebcamOn ? ( */}
          <>
            {remoteStream && remoteStream !== null && (
              <View style={styles.callerVideo}>
                <RTCView
                  streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()}
                  objectFit="cover"
                  style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                />
              </View>
            )}

            {localStream && (
              <RTCView
                streamURL={localStream.toURL()}
                objectFit="cover"
                style={styles.video}
              />
            )}
          </>
          {/* ) : (
            <View style={styles.cameraBlocked}>
              <LetterImage name={user.name} />
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="video-off-outline" size={50} />
              <Text>Camera is turned off</Text>
            </View>
          )} */}

          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: colors.black,
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-evenly",
              paddingVertical: 20,
            }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.btn}
              onPress={async () => {
                leave();

                InCallManager.stopRingback();
                InCallManager.stop();

                await callsApi.updateCallStatus({
                  callId,
                  callStatus: "finished",
                });

                navigation.reset({
                  index: 0,
                  routes: [
                    { name: "TabNavigator" },
                    { name: "AudioCall" },
                    { name: "VideoCall" },
                  ],
                });
              }}
            >
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                color={colors.white}
                name="phone"
                size={20}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[
                styles.btn,
                {
                  backgroundColor: colors.grey,
                },
              ]}
              onPress={() => toggleMic()}
            >
              {localMicOn ? (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="microphone"
                  size={20}
                  color={colors.primary_1100}
                />
              ) : (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="microphone-off"
                  size={20}
                  color={colors.primary_1100}
                />
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[
                styles.btn,
                {
                  backgroundColor: colors.grey,
                },
              ]}
              onPress={() => toggleCamera()}
            >
              {localWebcamOn ? (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="video-outline"
                  color={colors.primary_1100}
                  size={20}
                />
              ) : (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="video-off-outline"
                  color={colors.primary_1100}
                  size={20}
                />
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[
                styles.btn,
                {
                  backgroundColor: colors.grey,
                },
              ]}
              onPress={() => switchCamera()}
            >
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="camera-switch-outline"
                color={colors.primary_1100}
                size={20}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    // case "WEBRTC_ROOM":
    //   return (
    //     <OngoingCallModal
    //       localMicOn={localMicOn}
    //       localStream={localStream}
    //       localWebcamOn={localWebcamOn}
    //       remoteStream={remoteStream}
    //       hangup={async () => {
    //         leave();

    //         InCallManager.stopRingback();
    //         InCallManager.stop();

    //         await callsApi.updateCallStatus({
    //           callId,
    //           callStatus: "finished",
    //         });

    //         navigation.reset({
    //           index: 0,
    //           routes: [
    //             { name: "TabNavigator" },
    //             { name: "AudioCall" },
    //             { name: "VideoCall" },
    //           ],
    //         });
    //       }}
    //       switchCamera={switchCamera}
    //       toggleCamera={toggleCamera}
    //       toggleMic={toggleMic}
    //     />
    //   );

    case "VIDEO_CALL":
      return (
        <>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.contactInfo}>
              <View>
                {contact?.image ? (
                  <Image
                    source={contact?.image}
                    resizeMode="cover"
                    style={styles.userImage}
                  />
                ) : contact.name ? (
                  <LetterImage name={contact?.name} style={styles.userImage} />
                ) : (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons
                    color={colors.lightText}
                    name="account-circle"
                    size={50}
                  />
                )}

                <View style={styles.callInfo}>
                  <Text style={styles.callerName}>{contact?.name}</Text>

                  <Text style={styles.email}>{contact.mobile}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.circle}>
                <Image
                  source={require("../../../assets/images/video.jpg")}
                  style={styles.chatWindow}
                />
              </View>

              <View>
                {isCalling ? (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={async () => {
                      leave();

                      InCallManager.stopRingback();
                      InCallManager.stop();

                      await callsApi.updateCallStatus({
                        callId: callId || mainCallId,
                        callStatus: "finished",
                      });

                      navigation.reset({
                        index: 0,
                        routes: [
                          { name: "TabNavigator" },
                          { name: "AudioCall" },
                          { name: "VideoCall" },
                        ],
                      });
                    }}
                    style={[styles.callBtn, { backgroundColor: colors.danger }]}
                  >
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                      name="close"
                      style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                      size={20}
                    />

                    <Text style={styles.btnLabel}>Calling</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ) : (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      processCall();
                    }}
                    style={styles.callBtn}
                  >
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                      color={colors.white}
                      name="phone"
                      style={{ marginRight: 5 }}
                      size={20}
                    />

                    <Text style={styles.btnLabel}>Call</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )}

                <Text
                  style={[styles.bottomText, { fontFamily: "PoppinsMedium" }]}
                >
                  Call using:{" "}
                  <Text style={[styles.bottomText, { color: "#00000099" }]}>
                    {user.mobile}
                  </Text>
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </>
      );
    default:
      null;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    bottom: 50,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  bottomText: {
    fontSize: 11.1495,
    lineHeight: 17,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  btn: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.danger,
    borderRadius: 35,
    height: 55,
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 55,
  },
  btnLabel: {
    color: colors.white,
    fontFamily: "PoppinsMedium",
    fontSize: 14.866,
    lineHeight: 22,
  },
  callBtn: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.primary,
    borderRadius: 50,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 50,
    padding: 10,
    width: 150,
  },
  callInfo: {
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  callerName: {
    fontFamily: "PoppinsBold",
    fontSize: 16,
    letterSpacing: 0.5,
    lineHeight: 24,
  },
  circle: {
    borderRadius: 250,
    height: 312,
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginVertical: 20,
    width: 307.05,
  },
  container: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
  },
  email: {
    fontFamily: "Inter",
    fontSize: 12,
    letterSpacing: 0.1,
    lineHeight: 15,
  },
  cameraBlocked: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.black,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  callerVideo: {
    height: 200,
    right: 20,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 70,
    width: 120,
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  emoji: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  emojis: {
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  icon: {
    color: colors.white,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  iconContain: {
    alignItems: "center",
    borderColor: colors.white,
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderWidth: 2,
    height: 39.21,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    width: 38.58,
  },
  option: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    elevation: 1,
    borderRadius: 20.9368,
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    padding: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    width: "auto",
  },
  optionIcon: {
    marginHorizontal: 5,
    fontSize: 15,
  },
  options: {
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
  },
  contactInfo: {
    alignItems: "center",
    gap: 40,
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
  },
  userImage: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    borderRadius: 30,
    height: 55,
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: 55,
  },
  chatWindow: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
  },
  video: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
  },
  webRTCContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
});

export default VideoCallScreen;
```

And code for my peerconection setup

```
import { useRef } from "react";

import { mediaDevices, RTCPeerConnection } from "react-native-webrtc";

export const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
    },
    {
      urls: "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
    },
    {
      urls: "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
    },
    {
      urls: "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
    },
    {
      urls: "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302",
    },
    {
      urls: "stun:stun.relay.metered.ca:80",
    },
    {
      urls: "turn:standard.relay.metered.ca:80",
      username: "df6c0fa43e08de3464664fd4",
      credential: "TJdtVTyINKkVaUqb",
    },
    {
      urls: "turn:standard.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp",
      username: "df6c0fa43e08de3464664fd4",
      credential: "TJdtVTyINKkVaUqb",
    },
    {
      urls: "turn:standard.relay.metered.ca:443",
      username: "df6c0fa43e08de3464664fd4",
      credential: "TJdtVTyINKkVaUqb",
    },
    {
      urls: "turns:standard.relay.metered.ca:443?transport=tcp",
      username: "df6c0fa43e08de3464664fd4",
      credential: "TJdtVTyINKkVaUqb",
    },
  ],
};

const useUtils = () => {
  const peerConnection = useRef(new RTCPeerConnection(configuration));

  const closeAndReinstantiatePeerConnection = () => {
    // Close the current RTCPeerConnection
    peerConnection.current.close();

    // Create a new instance of RTCPeerConnection
    const newPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    // Update the ref with the new instance
    peerConnection.current = newPeerConnection;
  };

  const stopStreams = () => {
    if (peerConnection.current) {
      peerConnection.current.getSenders().forEach((sender) => {
        if (sender.track) {
          sender.track.stop();
        }
      });

      peerConnection.current.getReceivers().forEach((receiver) => {
        if (receiver.track) {
          receiver.track.stop();
        }
      });
    }
  };

  // async function getStream() {
  //   let isFront = true;
  //   const sourcesInfos = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

  //   let videoSourceId;

  //   for (let i = 0; i < sourcesInfos.length; i++) {
  //     const sourceInfo = sourcesInfos[i];

  //     if (
  //       sourceInfo.kind === "videoinput" &&
  //       sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? "front" : "environment")
  //     ) {
  //       videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
  //     }
  //   }

  //   const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  //     audio: true,
  //     video: {
  //       mandatory: {
  //         minWidth: 500,
  //         minFrameRate: 30,
  //         minHeight: 300,
  //       },
  //       deviceId: videoSourceId,
  //       facingMode: isFront ? "user" : "environment",
  //       frameRate: 30,
  //       height: 480,
  //       width: 640,
  //       optional: videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [],
  //     },
  //   });

  //   if (typeof stream != "boolean") return stream;

  //   return null;
  // }

  return {
    closeAndReinstantiatePeerConnection,
    configuration,
    // getStream,
    peerConnection,
    stopStreams,
  };
};

export default useUtils;
```

Please I really need help. I've been facing this problem for weeks and I have limited time to complete project. Please help me.

I put all the video call logic code into one file with using external components with the expectation that it'll work but it didn't.